# Change date when month is changed using month navigator in kendo UI date picker

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker

I am using kendo ui date picker,
I have a requirement that suppose currently 26 june 2014 is selected, when change the month using month naivgator to july, it should automatically select the 26 date in july month

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is a good to do it (based on user experience point of view).

Example: I already choose 26 June 2014, then I change the month by pressing the arrow to next month.
 I may just want to do it because I want to browse or check what is next month, without having intention to select the date from next month.

And what I see currently from kendo calendar, kendo already automatically mark the selected date (26) with the box, which is good from user experience perspective

[image]

So the answer is : it is not recommended to do it, unless you have strong reason to do it.

However, you still can probably do it by using navigate event handler

```
function onNavigate() {
       /*do something*/
}

$("#calendar").kendoCalendar({                   
        navigate: onNavigate
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, How can I do it same on datepicker